# Creating shortcuts with shell script

Tags: shortcuts, scripts

I have programed a java program. To run it I write `java -jar /path/name.jar` in the Terminal. I have made a script (.sh) which installs the program on the system. I want the script to create a shortcut to the Java program in both the desktop and the Launcher.

Anyone who know how to do it?

Comment: I believe you should properly *package* (`.deb`) your application. Is that what you're looking for? It will be a lot easier to accomplish what you want using a package.

Comment: It wasn't what I'm looking for, that's solved, but now I became interested. How can I package my application into a .deb-file?

Comment: I think this is worth a new question, now that you got some answers. Example: "How do I properly package my Java desktop application?" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Launcher apps are in `/usr/share/applications`.  I would create a `.desktop` file in that folder.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=My App Name
Exec=/path/to/java -jar /path/name.jar
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Icon=/path/to/my/icon.png
Categories=
```

Comment: I have another question: Does this work with Linux Mint or Fedora?

Comment: The format of the .desktop file should be the same, but the location is probably different.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about Launcher, but for shortcut to Desktop you can use symbolic link:

`ln -s /path_to_shell_script $HOME/Desktop`